# Was Mister Kitson and/or the planet of Kitson based on/named after George Kitson?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, agents-of-shield

In Marvel's *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* season 6, some of the protagonists find their way to the planet of Kitson, a planet that essentially has nothing but brothels and casinos. The planet is run by a Mr. Kitson. However, the creator of the comics *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* was based on is named George Kitson, who also directed an episode of the series ("Paradise Lost"). Was Kitson intentionally named after George Kitson? If so, did that happen in the comics, or begin in the TV series?

Comment: The wiki says that it is; https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Kitson

Comment: I suppose that's answer enough

Comment: If someone posted that as an answer, I'd instantly downvote it. Wikis are fan-written

Comment: @Valorum, Is imdb okay?

Comment: @shanu - Also fan-written. Plus a lot of their facts are copied verbatim from the wiki without any level of checking.

Comment: "Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Almost certainly. Agent of SHIELD writer George Kitson [repeatedly](https://twitter.com/search?lang=en-GB&q=planet%20(from%3Agakitson)&src=typed_query) makes reference to the planet on his Twitter account.

> I'm still waiting on those **Planet Kitson royalties**...
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/gakitson/status/1371568659928256516)</sup></sub>

and

> I’m not an actor by any means, but I was CTU background on 24, a hand
> double on CSI, and was dressed, but never on camera as a soldier in
> G.I. Joe. (Oh, and of course, **a profile of my face hung over the bar
> on the aptly named, infamous planet of Kitson in Agents of SHIELD**....)
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/gakitson/status/1376576081625411592)</sup></sub>

and

> **You’re welcome on my planet anytime**, Mr. Doyle! As the saying goes, what happens on Kitson.... (you know what, never mind what they say.)
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/gakitson/status/1278476234729549825)</sup></sub>

and

> **Q.** Did they name Kitson after you????
>
> **GK:** **Or was I named after Kitson?**
>
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/gakitson/status/1288547307412049921)</sup></sub>

Most notably, there was a giant picture of him emblazoned behind the bar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it indeed is.

Atleast according to the trivia page of that epsiode's [Imdb](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjO6NjQhJz5AhXMCIgKHcWzAjkQFnoECA4QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.imdb.com%2Ftitle%2Ftt8416904%2F&usg=AOvVaw07NTzcV4j3RFwT82aBJzSO)
"The planet Kitson is named after George Kitson, writer and story editor of several episodes. "

Comment: Maybe add a quote or something? The answer looks... really short...

Comment: @PeterNielsen - Also IMDB Trivia is fan-written and frequently inaccurate.